# jsPlumb dragging boxes off the screen prevention

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

Currently the boxes I create in jsPlumb can be dragged off the screen, how do I prevent the boxes not be able to be dragged to the most left side of my screen? Like shown in this picture:

[image]

My page also has a menu on top, how do I apply the same tactics to prevent from my boxes being able to go over the menu bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By making use of option **containment** you can restrict the boxes to be draggable inside a particular DIV:

```
$('#BoxId').draggable({
    containment: "#containerId",
    drag:function(e){
        jsPlumb.repaint($(this));
    }
});
```

for jsPlumb draggable:

```
jsPlumb.draggable($("BoxId"), {
    containment:"containerId" // no need of '#'
});
```

Comment: this is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/66/  
should would my #containerId be the div class name? @pruthvi bharadwaj

Comment: @Jenny I would recommend you to place all the boxes inside a single DIV(container) which will come under your menu bar. Later you can use the above option to restrict boxes inside the container.

Comment: I just added a <div id = 'body'>   </div> and that will create that div, then containment:"body" ? @Pruthvi Bharadwaj

Comment: I would recommend you to go for other name for div than "body". Yes, containment:"body" will do the job.

Comment: I needed to include the #, e.g. containment: "#main#